# Define simulink function that uses Stateflow chart as input

Tags: matlab, function, charts, simulink, stateflow

How can i define a simulink function that uses a stateflow chart as input? Let's say i've modeled a stateflow chart and i want to use it in a simulink function, so that my function take as argument the created statechart and it looks like:

```
my_simulink_function( StateflowChart b){ //do something on b }
```

Comment: You should probably use a library block which you can configure, if you're trying to pass a stateflow model around your larger model then your structuring is probably a bit weird. Without some more context about your model / what you're trying to do, this will be difficult to answer.

Comment: thank you for the response! i'll try to be a bit clearer. I need to visit each state of my chart like it's a directed graph, so i thought to create a simulink function to implement a standard graph traversal algorithm which takes as input the stateflow chart.